# ListView databinding to display usercontrols

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview

My goal is to add different Controls/UserControls in a WPF ListView. The Controls can be of any types. Here is an example of what it would look like with 3 different Controls/UserControls:

[image]

**WHAT WORKS**

This would work if I use the following XAML and code:

```
<ListView Name="ControlsListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Control"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here is the code:

```
ObservableCollection<Control> Controls { get; set; }
//...
ControlsListView.ItemsSource = Controls;
//...
Controls.Add(new ThresholdControl());
Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
Controls.Add(new Button()
                     {
                        Content = "Test"
                     });
```

**WHAT DOESN'T WORK**

My problem is when I want to add a level of indirection in the ObservableCollection. Instead of using directly a collection of Control, I would like to have a collection of MyItem. MyItem would itself contain the Control to display. Something like this:

```
class MyItem
{
    public Control MyControl { get; set; }
}
```

```
ObservableCollection<MyItem> Controls { get; set; }
```

And I would bind my ListView like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Control" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MyControl}"/>
```

When displaying a string, this will work ok, but for displaying a Control, this won't work. In fact, in my example, it would display the string representing the class of the Control inserted in the list instead of the Control itself.

What do I need to do to bind to the Controls in my list? DisplayMemberBinding doesn't seem to be the good choice here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the CellTemplate property instead of DisplayMemberBinding. You can then have your CellTemplate display the control you want. I think the code would look something like this:

```
<ListView Name="ControlsListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Control">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content={Binding MyControl} />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You bet and thanks for adding the DataTemplate tags. Sorry I forgot those, but it is nice to see that you didn't just blindly copy and paste but figured it out for yourself (that's why I upped your comment)